# Wrong email being passed to Google BigQuery from Google Data Studio

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a BigQuery view that I am trying to access from Google Data Studio:

```
select session_user() as session_user;
```

When I run it in BigQuery, it returns my email address just fine. However, when I access the same view from Google Data Studio, the query doesn't return my email address, but rather, it returns, "cloud-dataengine-adminbot@system.gserviceaccount.com". The data source in Data Studio is set to use the viewer's credentials, not the owner's. Any tips as to why it doesn't pull back the email address of the Data Studio user? This is just a test query, the actual query is supposed to pull back rows where an email field matches the viewer's email.

Comment: I can reproduce. Perhaps our good friend @Felipe Hoffa can shed some light..

Comment: I was able to work around this by using a custom query with the BigQuery connector and using the @DS_USER_EMAIL parameter.

Comment: session_user() works from a custom query as well.

Comment: I tired as custom query and it did not work for me.